# How to detect screen size change / device rotation in ReactXP?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, reactxp

Is there, say, an event I can hook up to, to detect a screen size change, so that I can make my elements responsively resize themselves?

I'm half-way there, in that I can retrieve the current size of my top-level  element, through the [UserInterface](https://microsoft.github.io/reactxp/docs/apis/userinterface) API:

```
  UserInterface.measureLayoutRelativeToWindow(that).then(dimensions => {
    // dimensions.width, dimensions.height
  });
```

But this is just a one-off call. I now want to subscribe a handler that will get called whenever the "window" resizes. E.g. a desktop user resizes the browser window or a mobile user rotates the device 90°.

Does ReactXP have an API for this yet?

Comment: please refer to this package https://github.com/yamill/react-native-orientation

Comment: +Harrison thanks , I’ll check that out. However I’m wondering if ReactXP itself implements this. I would prefer to use a ReactXP interface that works across web and native, as opposed to hacking in a react-native call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, found the solution: subscribing to the onLayout event of the [View component](https://microsoft.github.io/reactxp/docs/components/view.html) causes the handler to fire whenever the window or screen size changes (including rotation).

Code:

```
onLayout() {
  UserInterface
    .measureLayoutRelativeToWindow(this)
    .then(screenSize =>
      console.log("event", event));
}

onLayout(event: ViewOnLayoutEvent) {
    console.log("event", event);
}

...
<View onLayout={this.onLayout}>
    ...
</View>
```

Output:

```
event {x: 0, y: 0, width: 840, height: 1639}
```

I guess this is consistent with the [onLayout event of ReactNative's View component](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/view#onlayout).

For this to work, the View has to be the top-level element of the React tree. It won't work for a View nested within something else.